# Facebook javascript sdk not returning email address

Tags: javascript, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a **fb.api()** request to the Facebook api but am unable to get the email address of the user.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,id', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  });
```

When I make this api request an object is returned by Facebook which only has the `id` AND `name` of the user but does not give me the email address of the user

I have asked for email permission and the user has granted it

Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I hope this one addresses your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707189/facebook-oauth-retrieve-user-email?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

ok i find out the problem. my application was not live and was on testing mode...as soon as i make my facebook app public it started to work and started giving me the email address of the users