# How facebook login integration works internally?

Tags: java, web-applications, single-sign-on, facebook-login

I want to integrate my web application with facebook but first i want to know how it works technically. Everywhere on google/youtube i find steps to integrate my 
application with facebook but nowhere it is explained how it works technically like

1) When i click facebook login on my website what user information go to facebook and what information goes from app developer. I believe sessionid in cookies but what else ?

2) what response facebook returns to my web app.

3) How my application will determine its the same  returning user as multiple users can have same name. Does FB shares constant unique identifier  with my app
each time user is authenticated ? Does this unique identifier is per web application ?

Is there a good resource in this context or some one can explain it, it will be great.

**Here is my own understanding how oAuth facebook login integration works after reading this [manually-build-a-login-flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)  and [30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/)**

Say my web application name is `www.LearnSocialLogin.com` where i want to integrate with facebook login. Here are high level technical/internal  steps which takes place
behind scenes :-

1. I will register on facebook with my webapplication and returning url as   www.LearnSocialLogin.com. It will generate appId(sort of public key) and appSecret(sort of private key)
2. I will display the facebook login dialog on my web application
3. If user is already logged in, user can do single-sign-on option, allowing him to leverage his existing facebook session
4. If authentication is successful then FB displays another dialogue asking for permission
5. If user says yes,  request will go to FB server and server send back the unique code and redirect the user to  my www.LearnSocialLogin.com server .
6. Them my web application connects with FB API with that unique code and app secret
7. FB will generate the token code
8. Now web application(www.LearnSocialLogin.com) server side validates the token with FB server and get the user_id alogwith other data in response

**Is this process correct ?**

If yes, my question is on user_id sent by FB server in step... I believe  FB will send the same user_id each token is authenticated. Right ?
If yes Does FB send the same user_id per web application or is it same per user for all web applications ?

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Facebook-Twitter-and-Google-using-OAuth-for-their-external-authentication-services-instead-of-OpenID-or-SAML-What-are-the-differences

Comment: @mm759 yes this was useful but does not provide all details. But still not on clear on point 3 . Say i login to  stackoverflow using FB first time and post a question.Now logout. Login back to SO with FB authentication , how so will link me to profile where i created the question. I mean is there any unique identifier that FB will communicate to SO on each login ?

Comment: If you can identify a user uniquely using his/her EmailID, then there is a simple solution. The response object has an email attribute when the Sign On is complete. Refer to this if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707189/facebook-oauth-retrieve-user-email

Comment: @ShaswatRungta I am not sure how does other sites like stackoverflow can identify the user coming from FB ? Do they also do it on based on some info like user emailId ?

Comment: @user3198603 When you try to get the login status from Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#checklogin), the response object has a user_id if the user gets authenticated. This user_id identifies a user uniquely for Facebook. You can use the same for your account as well.

Comment: @user3198603 basically the choice is yours. Once you authenticate a user from Facebook, in the response, you get certain information about the user (his name, DOb, email ID or any of the other parameters requested by your app/website). It is upon you what you want to consider as a primary key for your app/site. 
I am not sure how SO does it though, but I am guessing it would be something similar.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta Thanks . As you said `When you try to get the login status from Facebook the response object has a user_id if the user gets authenticated`is user_id same across the clients(clients here mean my webapp or some one else webapp) ?

Comment: Yes this is the user_id from Facebook's perspective. So common across the apps. You can try to do it yourself by replicating your code with a different appid and appsecret.