# unable to get email from facebook login in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, facebook, authentication

I am working on a website. I added fb login to the website but the problem is I am not getting the email id, only able to fetch name, id, profile.
Can some help me. this is my code:

```
function _getFacebookProfileDetails() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        FB.api('/me','GET', { fields: 'id, first_name, last_name, email, picture' }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response || response.error) {
                deferred.reject('Error occured');
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the email permission to get the email address. Look at 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707189/facebook-oauth-retrieve-user-email/5710498#5710498)

Comment: I already requested for this.  **FB.api('/me','GET', { fields: 'id, first_name, last_name, email, picture' },**

Comment: @user10428712 that is the fields you are requesting in your API call, that is _not_ where you ask for permission, that happens during login.

Comment: How to do that? plz help

Comment: follow this official  FB SDK link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v3.2